# How to set the bookmarking (cmi.location) for SCORM 1.2?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2, canvas-lms

I tried to bookmarking for flash SCORM 1.2 packages. I'm properly capturing the last visited data(cmi.loation, suspend data),  but when I'm trying to reset the data for next launch, SCO is not relocating, it is starting from beginning.

And I set the hard coded values in LMSInitilization() function in javascript.

I used bellow code for setting the location variable to SCO.

```
// cmi data model storing object

var cmiobj = new Object();

function LMSInitialize(dummyString) {




        // already initialized or already finished
        if ((flagInitialized) || (flagFinished)) { return "false"; }

        // set initialization flag
        flagInitialized = true;

        this.cmiobj["cmi.core.lesson_location"]="6";
        this.cmiobj['cmi.core.lesson_status']='incomplete';
        this.cmiobj['cmi.core.session_time']='00:00:50';
        this.cmiobj['cmi.suspend_data']='FA1Enon ... "; 

        // return success value
        return "true";

    }
```

Hope you help.

Comment: I'm on my phone, but I didn't see a call to LMSCommit('');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `cmi.core.exit` to `"suspend"` too - otherwise it will not supply any of the old data for you to continue with next time.

Comment: Thanks Rycochet for you response, I tried with cmi.core.exit but it's not working. and cmi.core.exit I'm getting as undefined last time.                <pre>   
   this.cache["cmi.core.lesson_location"]="5";
   this.cache['cmi.core.lesson_status']='incomplete';
   this.cache['cmi.core.exit']='suspend';
   this.cache['cmi.core.session_time']='00:00:50';
   this.cache['cmi.suspend_data']='FA1Enone$nP1Enone$nP1En</pre>

Comment: If you check on here - http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/ - then cmi.core.exit is WO, so you can't actually read any value from it (should return an empty string and set an error code if you try). The other thing that might play a part is the platform itself needs to allow resume - have you tried the content pack on SCORM Cloud?

Comment: Thanks Rycochet, I will go through on that site.

Comment: Resume functionality is working properly, I missed out to set the cmi.children, [cmi.core._children]="student_id, student_name, lesson_location, credit, lesson_status, entry, score, total_time, exit, session_time";